# Checkout recently created branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

So. I have done some strange steps to get this result:

Let's say we have a branch called `dev`. I'm on it at the moment.

There's another one branch called `dev2`. That branch is already created remotely, but I do not have that one locally.

So, what I did is `git checkout -b dev2`, which created a new branch called `dev2` locally on top of the `dev` branch.
After this, I just did `git pull origin dev2`, so it got all the things, that was in the `dev` branch.
I got a message saying that I have to fix some CONFLICTS. So I did that. Committed my fixes and pushed them. Now `dev2` branch is not what it was before remotely.

Is there a way to get back my beloved `dev2` branch to it's normal state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If another branch `dev2` has been pushed by someone else, that way to get it locally is (in:

```
git checkout master
git branch -d dev2
git fetch
git checkout -b dev2 origin/dev2
```

The second command delete the '`dev2`' branch you did, because you don't have to merge anything yet: you just have to fetch and reference `dev2`.

Later, you can merge `dev2` to `dev`, and resolve merge conflict then.

Note: this won't work if you already push (as in `git push --force dev2`) back to the upstream repo.

Answer (score 1):

You can check which commit on the remote you want to rollback to, then hard reset to it

```
git log origin/dev2          # See history on remote
```

From the output of this command, identify the  of the commit you want to go back to (for example, 3157ee3718e180a9476bf2e5cab8e3f1e78a73b7)

Then rollback to that commit and update the remote

```
git checkout dev2             # Go to branch dev2
git stash                     # Discard your current changes
git reset --hard <hash>       # Reset to the state of the hash
git push --force origin dev2  # Forcefully update the remote
```